# Breaker; breaker;

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Will constantly turning the power off/on manually (one to four times a day) at the circuit breaker box cause any damage to the box itself or to the wiring in the specific room and will it most likely result with a higher utility bill?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the breaker is rated as switch-duty (SWD), there should be no problem switching in ON/OFF many times.

Comment: I appreciate the info. What if it's not SWD? Still okay?

Comment: @JandJ if it's not switch-duty, then using like a switch will wear it out.

Answer (score 0):

Right.   The only foreseeable problem you could ever have with this procedure would be wearing out the breaker itself over a period of time.